# Why can't IntelliJ resolve the pom.xml file?

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

Building a Java Spring application, using Maven. However, the entire pom.xml file for dependencies and such had every single keyword give the error "Cannot resolve symbol":
[image: Pom.xml full of errors snapshot]

Comment: Do you have the Maven plugin enabled? The icon that is shown in the screenshot is not the normal icon that IntelliJ shows for a `pom.xml` file.

Comment: I agree with @WimDeblauwe, it looks like IntelliJ is trying to open it as an ANT build definition instead of a Maven file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have [added](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/adding-build-file-to-project.html) this pom.xml as an Ant build file.

Instead you should add it as a Maven project file into IDE. You can do so by [adding it](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/delegate-build-and-run-actions-to-maven.html#link_unlink_maven_project) from Maven tool window:

1. Open the Maven tool window.
2. In the Maven tool window, click the `+` icon to attach a Maven project.
3. In the dialog that opens, select the desired `pom.xml` file, and click OK.